# How to escape a native SQL function in perl bind_param()?

Tags: sql-server, perl

So I have the following snippet code:

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO mytbl (first_name, last_name, birthdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Error:".$dbh->errstr;                 

$sth->bind_param(1, $fname);
$sth->bind_param(2, $lname);
$sth->bind_param(3, $bdate);
$sth->execute() or die "Execution failed: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth->finish();
```

When performing insertion in Microsoft SQL with the following data for birthdate,
$bdate = "2010-01-06"; I have to cast it into the datetime function with SQL,

```
$bdate = "cast ('$eml_form_end_dt' as datetime)";
```

This, however, caused problem as perl doesn't recognize it. What I had to do instead is:

```
$bdate = "cast ('$eml_form_end_dt' as datetime)";
my $sql = "INSERT INTO mytbl (first_name, last_name, birthdate VALUES (?, ?, '$bdate')";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Error:".$dbh->errstr;                 

$sth->bind_param(1, $fname);
$sth->bind_param(2, $lname);
# This causes problem
# $sth->bind_param(3, "cast ('$eml_form_end_dt' as datetime)");
$sth->execute() or die "Execution failed: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth->finish();
```

How do I escape the SQL function in this case?

EDIT: this is the error message I received:
DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid precisi
on value (SQL-HY104) at filename.pl.

Comment: @John: can you say exactly what the problems are (e.g. the message you got)?  Hunch - there's a space between the CAST function name and the opening bracket - could that be part of the issue?

Comment: sorry I may not be very clear. So my question is I would love call the sql function cast <myvar> as 'datetime' and store it as an variable so it can be binded. I tried removing the space as you pointed out, it doesnt fix the problem. Please see my edit for the error message.

Comment: The first case won't work because the entire point of placeholders is *making* that not work. The second case doesn't work because you have quotes that don't belong. Try printing out the SQL statement you're generating and the problem should be obvious.

Comment: @hobbs - The SQL query (without binding params) is absolutely fine

Comment: What versions of DBD::ODBC and the SQL Server driver are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that bind parameters only allow you to pass values, not arbitrary SQL expressions. This is very much by design, since the other way would eliminate the main benefits of bind variables: caching compiled statements and preventing SQL injection attacks. So the function has to go into your SQL:

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO mytbl (first_name, last_name, birthdate VALUES (?, ?, cast(? as datetime))";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Error:".$dbh->errstr;                 

$sth->bind_param(1, $fname);
$sth->bind_param(2, $lname);
$sth->bind_param(3, $eml_form_end_dt);
$sth->execute() or die "Execution failed: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth->finish();
```

That ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is

```
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
...
$sth->bind_param(3, $bdate, SQL_DATETIME);
```

to tell DBI the correct type to use (it defaults to varchar).  You might need to use `SQL_DATE` instead of `SQL_DATETIME`; I don't use SQL Server myself.

Comment: @cjm - thanks, it does looks like what I am looking for. But when I applied your code, I am getting back "Optional feature not implemented" (DBI::SQL_DATETIME) or "Bareword "SQL_DATETIME" not allowed while "strict subs" in use. I am using ActivePerl and mssql 2005.

Comment: You get the bareword warning because you didn't `use DBI qw(:sql_types);` (which imports that constant).  Maybe the driver you're using doesn't support SQL_DATETIME.  Did you try SQL_DATE or SQL_TIMESTAMP instead?

Comment: @cjm-I added the import statement, also doubled check DBI.pm and saw SQL_DATETIME is documented. However, both SQL_DATETIME and SQL_DATE return the same message: optional feature not implemented. So it is very likely the driver (ODBC) doesn't support this. Any other routes that I can take?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure MS SQL will convert the string to a date without any casting. Did you have a problem binding '2010-01-06' to the placeholder? If that doesn't work, then you can use the 3rd argument of bind_param to tell what type the argument is. Or you can try:

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO mytbl (first_name, last_name, birthdate) VALUES (?, ?, cast(? as datetime))";
```

and bind the string version of the date to that placeholder.

Update: Amazing how many people (including me) missed the missing right paren.

Comment: @runrig - Without casting the date, it will, for example, convert 2009-12-24 to 1905-05-28. I also tried your solution, it returns err msg "invalid precision value".

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

`INSERT INTO mytbl (first_name, last_name, birthdate VALUES (?, ?, cast(? as datetime))`

be this:

`INSERT INTO mytbl (first_name, last_name, birthdate) VALUES (?, ?, cast(? as datetime))`